# Calling a method from an event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this code I am working on but every time I call init method I keep  getting an error:

> this.addElement is not a function

Is it because I can't call methods from event handlers?

```
function editor () {

    this.init = function () {
        $("#area").bind('click' , this.click_event );
        
    }

    this.addElement = function () {
        console.log("adding element");
    }

    this.click_event = function(event) {
        this.addElement();
        console.log("click event in x : "+event.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can definitely call methods from event handlers. The question is, what is `this`, inside `click_event`? Understand that, and the world is your shellfish.

Comment: even when I remove "this" i still get the same error

Comment: If you remove `this`, it is still there implicitly: `this.addElement()` is the same as `addElement()`. But inspect `this` - it is quite likely it's not what you wanted.

Comment: inside your click callback, `this` doesn't point to the object of `editor` anymore. Do a `console.log(this)` inside `addElement` to find out what `this` is referring to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function editor () {
    var that = this;

    this.init = function () {
        $("#area").bind('click' , this.click_event );

    }

    this.addElement = function () {
        console.log("adding element");
    }

    this.click_event = function(event) {
        that.addElement();
        console.log("click event in x : "+event.data);
    }
}
```

You should read this book, [JavaScript: the Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) and visit the Crockenator's web site here, [crockford.com](http://crockford.com)

You can also read about the JavaScript "this" issue here, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: @Ayoub: Basically, `this` is very different in JavaScript than it is in some other languages, like Java or C#. It's determined entirely by how a function is *called*, not where it's defined. More: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html

Answer (score 0):

Fast forward 12 years and we now have arrow functions :-)

I faced something similar and wrote up how I solved it with an arrow function.
Though it's on salesforce.stackexchange.com, it's about `this` in core Javascript:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/381194/in-an-lwc-how-can-a-function-which-is-called-from-an-event-listener-refer-to-a/381195#381195